# How to reduce Amazon RDS PostgreSQL storage usage?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres DB in Amazon RS.

When I ask DB about it's size it gives me:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('mydb'));
> 333 GB.
```

However the RDS instance is already using 2TB of storage and getting bigger and bigger every day.

1. What can possibly cause such behavior?
2. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you doing [routine vacuuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) in your DB? Also, you may find [this wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage) useful to get more insight than just database size function provides.

Comment: 1. Routine vacuuming is configured, however looks like it cannot be executed right now due to luck of storage. 2. Sum of tables usage from queries <= 333 GB, so I still cannot understand who is using all that space.

Comment: If you look on [AWS RDS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#CHAP_Storage.FactsAbout) on "Other Factors That Impact Storage Performance", then look also amount of backups and other factors mentioned there.

Comment: If I understand this article right this factors can affect performance (how fast DB is), not how many storage is used on AWS instance. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Backups, transaction logs, and snapshots are also stored under that instance.

Answer (score 0):

execute ***vacuum full*** command, be carefull because generate lock ( vacull full)

Comment: Sorry this didn't help. It removed only ~10GB of usage.

Comment: This might be of help => https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/routine-vacuuming.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the space occupied by the logs

Comment: add some more details about what you have tried and what probelm you are facing .